# TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index while assigning a variable

Tags: python, pandas

While reading the data, with typing only the command below, my data appeared as 1 column and some rows (although I have 40 columns)

```
data = "mydata.csv" 
df = pd.read_csv(data,sep=", ", thousands=',' )
```

Becuse of that, I run the following command, it made my data as 40 columns and some rows (which are the correct numbers for rows and columns

```
names= df.columns.str.split(',').tolist()
df= df.iloc[:,0].str.split(',', expand=True)
df.columns = names
```

But the problem is it made all the columns object but I wanted to made them float64. So I run the following

```
df = df.apply(lambda col:pd.to_numeric(col, errors='coerce'))
```

Now the problem is that when I run the following line

```
X = df['""USDTRY""']
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

How can I solve it?
Any help would be appreciated.

My data looks as follows:

```
    "USDTRY"    "EURTRY"    "EURUSD"    "BIST100"   "TR2YT" "BRENT" "WTI"   "Altin" "GUmus" "UFE"   "TUGE"  "Cari_Denge"    "Issizlik"  "X1...16"   "X2...17"   "X1...18"   "X2...19"   "X1...20"   "X2...21"   "X1...22"   "X2...23"   "X1...24"   "X2...25"   "X1...26"   "X2...27"   "X1...28"   "X2...29"   "X1...30"   "X2...31"   "X1...32"   "X2...33"   "X1...34"   "X2...35"   "X1...36"   "X2...37"   "X1...38"   "X2...39"   "X1...40"   "X2...41"
0   1.3570  1.6590  1.2230  300.1512    16.97   64.87   67.20   436.7000    6.730   11.12   8.81    -8.760000e+08   9.4 1.3550  1.3425  1.6530  1.6580  1.2217  1.2343  304.6157    309.0802    16.925  16.880  67.57   67.02   69.81   68.94   430.9000    435.0000    6.730   6.820   11.12   11.12   8.81    8.81    -8.760000e+08   -8.760000e+08   9.4 9.4
1   1.3440  1.6221  1.2029  333.3323    15.71   63.48   66.24   468.8000    7.440   10.91   8.10    -1.800000e+07   9.6 1.3570  1.3550  1.6590  1.6530  1.2230  1.2217  300.1512    304.6157    16.970  16.925  64.87   67.57   67.20   69.81   436.7000    430.9000    6.730   6.730   11.12   11.12   8.81    8.81    -8.760000e+08   -8.760000e+08   9.4 9.4
2   1.3480  1.6230  1.2031  333.9623    15.81   63.84   66.79   472.0000    7.480   10.91   8.10    -1.800000e+07   9.6 1.3440  1.3570  1.6221  1.6590  1.2029  1.2230  333.3323    300.1512    15.710  16.970  63.48   64.87   66.24   67.20   468.8000    436.7000    7.440   6.730   10.91   11.12   8.10    8.81    -1.800000e+07   -8.760000e+08   9.6 9.4
3   1.3480  1.6230  1.2039  327.4495    15.89   63.93   66.35   469.0000    7.330   10.91   8.10    -1.800000e+07   9.6 1.3480  1.3440  1.6230  1.6221  1.2031  1.2029  333.9623    333.3323    15.810  15.710  63.84   63.48   66.79   66.24   472.0000    468.8000    7.480   7.440   10.91   10.91   8.10    8.10    -1.800000e+07   -1.800000e+07   9.6 9.6
4   1.3530  1.6163  1.2015  333.1918    15.73   62.97   65.07   462.0000    7.270   10.91   8.10    -1.800000e+07   9.6 1.3480  1.3480  1.6230  1.6230  1.2039  1.2031  327.4495    333.9623    15.890  15.810  63.93   63.84   66.35   66.79   469.0000    472.0000    7.330   7.480   10.91   10.91   8.10    8.10    -1.800000e+07   -1.800000e+07   9.6 9.6
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
4126    8.5745  10.4980 1.2189  1447.0800   18.15   71.49   69.23   1898.9962   27.875  42.89   69.70   -1.127000e+09   10.6    8.5979  8.5787  10.4565 10.4588 1.2171  1.2178  1447.5900   1449.1700   18.090  18.180  72.22   72.22   70.05   69.96   1892.8199   1888.2983   27.635  27.751  42.89   42.89   69.70   69.70   -1.127000e+09   -1.127000e+09   10.6    10.6
4127    8.6563  10.5460 1.2165  1432.9300   18.15   71.89   69.62   1889.9700   27.780  42.89   69.70   -1.127000e+09   10.6    8.5745  8.5979  10.4980 10.4565 1.2189  1.2171  1447.0800   1447.5900   18.150  18.090  71.49   72.22   69.23   70.05   1898.9962   1892.8199   27.875  27.635  42.89   42.89   69.70   69.70   -1.127000e+09   -1.127000e+09   10.6    10.6
4128    8.6905  10.5519 1.2124  1428.1300   18.10   71.31   68.81   1870.5699   27.450  42.89   69.70   -1.127000e+09   10.6    8.6563  8.5745  10.5460 10.4980 1.2165  1.2189  1432.9300   1447.0800   18.150  18.150  71.89   71.49   69.62   69.23   1889.9700   1898.9962   27.780  27.875  42.89   42.89   69.70   69.70   -1.127000e+09   -1.127000e+09   10.6    10.6
4129    8.5826  10.4903 1.2209  1430.7300   18.10   71.35   68.83   1907.9440   28.200  42.89   69.70   -1.127000e+09   10.6    8.6905  8.6563  10.5519 10.5460 1.2124  1.2165  1428.1300   1432.9300   18.100  18.150  71.31   71.89   68.81   69.62   1870.5699   1889.9700   27.450  27.780  42.89   42.89   69.70   69.70   -1.127000e+09   -1.127000e+09   10.6    10.6
4130    8.5301  10.4241 1.2211  1432.0400   18.09   70.25   67.72   1900.1899   27.900  42.89   69.70   -1.127000e+09   10.6    8.5826  8.6905  10.4903 10.5519 1.2209  1.2124  1430.7300   1428.1300   18.100  18.100  71.35   71.31   68.83   68.81   1907.9440   1870.5699   28.200  27.450  42.89   42.89   69.70   69.70   -1.127000e+09   -1.127000e+09   10.6    10.6
```

Thanks.

Comment: Adding a sample data would make it easier to check the issue.

Comment: I edited the question with adding sample data.

Comment: this doesnot have all the columns and hence it would be difficult to reproduce the issue, can you add few records, with all the columns instead. Also, i see that you have mentioned thousand separator in the read_csv, so does this mean the data is in string format or it is just formatted as comma seperated but actually saved as plain numbers ?

Comment: I added all the columns. It is actually just formatted as comma separated and and plain numbers.

Comment: With the sample data you provided, i was able to load data with just `pd.read_csv('mydata.csv')`, without any issue. and even the `X = df["USDTRY"]`, worked fine